# relativeSize isn't adjusting HStack dimensions

Tags: swiftui

When .relativeSize is called on HStack{}, the borders do not come closer. Indicative of dimensions not being adjusted.

I've already tried rearranging the sequence of method calls on HStack, such that .relativeSize is called before and after .frame and .border

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 1){
            //Top box holding a rectangle
            HStack{
                Text("Test")
            }
            .frame(width: 355, height: 99, alignment: .center)
            .relativeSize(width: 0.95, height: 0.95)
            .border(Color.blue, width: 2)

            //Bottom box holding 3 recangles
            HStack{
                Text("Test")
            }
            .frame(width: 355, height: 47, alignment: .center)
            .border(Color.red, width: 1)
        }
        .frame(width: 355, height: 148, alignment: .center)
        .border(Color.black, width: 1)

    //body paren
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you call frame and relativeSize on the same view?

Comment: Because if I got rid of frame, the border collapsed to fit the Text content.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a Spacer() before and after the text, and remove the .frame() modifier. This way the HStack will expand laterally as much as 0.95 the size of the containing VStack. Is this what you want?

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 1){
            //Top box holding a rectangle
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Text("Test")
                Spacer()
                }
                .relativeSize(width: 0.95, height: 0.95)
                .border(Color.blue, width: 2)

            //Bottom box holding 3 recangles
            HStack{
                Text("Test")

                }
                .frame(width: 355, height: 47, alignment: .center)
                .border(Color.red, width: 1)
            }
            .frame(width: 355, height: 148, alignment: .center)
            .border(Color.black, width: 1)

        //body paren
    }

}
```